# what's the difference between ClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("./path") and ClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("path")

Tags: java

I have a spring boot project, and packaged to a war.
in my project I need read a file as resource.
and this way is work fine
DemoApplication.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("META/app.properties")//this way works

but when I add a "./" in front of the path ,it won't work
DemoApplication.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("./META/app.properties")//this way didn't work

and two ways both work fine if didn't use spring boot ,like just usual way to running in tomcat.

so what the difference?
sorry my English not good enough.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. It would be better if you checkout [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for future endeavour at Stack overflow.Great question tend to provide quicker, better answers from the community  -Thank you

Comment: Presumably it's because while `./` isn't valid for reading a compressed jar, your Tomcat setup is exploding to disk, and the OS is handling it for you.

Comment: @chrylis thanks.i think I see what you mean